# Two subspaces of a Hilbert space are equal if their orthogonal complements are equal

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I have the question: "If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are subspaces of the hilbert space $H$, and they satisfy $F_1^\bot=F_2^\bot$, is it true that $F_1=F_2$?"

I would say that is it true, as one have that if $X$ is a linear subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, then $(X^\bot)^\bot=X$.

With the above fact I would show this with:
$$F_1^\bot=F_2^\bot\quad\quad\Rightarrow\quad\quad (F_1^\bot)^\bot=(F_2^\bot)^\bot\quad\quad\Rightarrow\quad\quad F_1=F_2$$
However I doubt whether the argument is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument is not valid (and the assertion is not true): The point is, that in general you only have 
$$ F^{\bot\bot} = \bar F $$
that is your argument only works for closed subspaces.

To give a counterexample, $F_1 = c_{00}$, $F_2 = c_0$ of $H = c_0$. Then $F_1^\bot = F_2^\bot = 0$, but $F_1 \ne F_2$.